# URL with trailing slash working in local but not in server using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my rewrite rule in .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 "http://example.com
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

I need the URL like `http://example.com/careers/` instead of  `http://example.com/careers.php`
And also `http://example.com/careers/designer` instead of  `http://example.com/apply.php?jobs=designer`
This is working fine in my local but not in live server. In server this is leading to `page not found` page.

Please provide me a solution.

Comment: The above certainly does _not_ rewrite `http://example.com/careers/designer` as described.

Comment: If it's working in local, not in server, that means mod_rewrite isn't enabled properly in your server. Check with your host to enable the mod_rewrite extension.

Answer (score 0):

This should rewrite exactly like what you describe in your question, except that you once name `careers.php`, once `apply.php` as script name, which sounds odd...:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^careers/(.+)$ /careers.php?jobs=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^careers/?$ /careers.php [L]
```

A more general implementation might be this variant, but your question is vague in details, so be careful with too much flexibility without actually having defined clear goals:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1.php?jobs=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

*A general note*:

these are the versions for `.htaccess` style files. You'd have to change the syntax slightly and include the normal leading slashes (`/`) to the patterns to use those lines inside the normal host configuration. If you have access to that configuration you should *always* prefer it to using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, surprisingly hard to debug and *really* slow the server down for nothing. You should only fall back to their usage if you have no access to the real server configuration.